# Remove set of characters in a string in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

I want to remove all of the following characters from a field: `*` `-` `:` `.`

Currently I can do this by chaining `TRANSLATE` statements together, but I hope there's an easier way.

#### INPUT

```
SELECT field FROM myTable
```

```
| field |
=========
| asdf* |
| as.df |
| a-sdf |
| :asdf |
```

#### DESIRED OUTPUT

```
| field |
=========
| asdf  |
| asdf  |
| asdf  |
| asdf  |
```

#### MY CODE

```
SELECT TRANSLATE(TRANSLATE(TRANSLATE(TRANSLATE(field, '*', ''), '-', ''), ':', ''), '.', '')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`translate()` takes longer strings:

```
select translate(field, '*-:.', '')
```

You might be confusing it with `replace()`, where you would need to nest the functional calls.